# Dynamically adding class to <span> that equals value of field/property

Tags: angular

I'm still new to Angular so bear with me.

I've got a TagComponent that contains a Color-enum and has one such color as a property/field. I want Angular to automatically add this color as a class, so that Semantic UI can format that color.

How can I do this? I've tried ng-class, but it won't accept ng-class="{{tag?.color}}".

// tag.model.ts

```
export class Tag {
    private _color: Tag.Color;
    private _name: string;

    constructor(color: Tag.Color, name: string){
        // checking name.length in the form!
        this._name = name;
        this._color = color;
    }

    get color() : Tag.Color {
        return this._color;
    }

    get name() : string {
        return this._name;
    }

}
export module Tag{
    export enum Color{
        Red,
        Orange,
        Yellow,
        Olive,
        Green,
        Teal,
        Blue,
        Violet,
        Purple,
        Pink,
        Brown,
        Grey
    }
}
```

// tag.component.html

```
<p class="ui pointing basic label">{{marker?.name}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like this:

```
<p class="ui pointing basic label" [style.color]="marker.color">{{marker?.name}}</p>
```

For more examples, look here:
https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/

P.S. `ngClass` is used for conditional application of CSS classes. For example, `[ngClass]="{ 'colorClass': marker.name === 'bob'}"` means that if the condition `marker.name === 'bob'` is `true` then apply the CSS class `colorClass`.

---

Based on the comment bellow, this is a more relevant solution.

```
<p [class]="'ui pointing basic label ' + marker.color">{{marker?.name}}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm not trying to set the color directly, however. I want to add the color-string, e.g. "red", "orange", to the list of classes. This way, Semantic UI will style my element based on that class name.

Comment: Oh, then you could always just do `<p [class]="'ui pointing basic label ' + marker.color">{{marker?.name}}</p>`

Comment: That just seems to remove all of the classes in my case, even though I have the appropriate @Input() marker : Marker in my component file. I seem to have forgotten something elsewhere.

Comment: Adding `[]` brackets to an HTML property in Angular just makes it so that the contents of the attribute will be executed as JS. So in the example above, it will set `class` to the string literal returned by adding `marker.color` to `'ui pointing basic label'`. Even if `marker.color` was an invalid class, the browser should still render your remaining styles.

Comment: I don't understand how the `@Input` plays into this without seeing additional code.

Comment: I just figured it out, apparently I had to write this: `<p class="ui tiny tag label {{marker?.color}}">{{marker?.name}}</p>`. Learning Angular is really humbling.

Comment: Ah, that works too. Using Angular's template string interpolation rather than a computed field. Noice.